# parallel application checkpointing in java

Tags: java, synchronization, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, checkpoint

does anyone know a parallel aplication/benchmark in java that simulates checkpointing? i mean, in my cluster there are running parallel processes in diferent nodes and i want to make them concurrently do some specific action (to have a checkpoint for example). this synchronization how is it achieved?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the concurrent threads run in the same VM, just use a CyclicBarrier or a Latch. If they run in different VMs, you can use Terracotta to share a Latch or CyclicBarrier across JVMs, on which all your servers can then synchronize.
Works great, but it needs some work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try hazelcast which offer this functionality but has a lighter touch on the rest of your system than terracotta (more than you need just for this)